# What happens to Lord Brahma after a Kalpa and after a Mahakalpa?

Tags: puranas, brahma, kalpa, pralaya

1.Does Lord Brahma **sleeps** after each kalpa and then again **wakes** up after pralaya and again does creation or he **merges** into the Lord after each kalpa and **manifests** again?

2.If he manifests in each Kalpa, then how we take his lifespan to be 100 years? (Because if he is reborn after each kalpa so his age should be only 1 day with respect to his time)

Please someone answer this with scriptural texts if possible.

Comment: he sleeps in the night

Comment: Please provide scriptural reference :) That would help a lot ! @AdityaDwivedi

Comment: As you see he can't die in the night so he must sleep/meditate or do any such thing

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi what are ur views on this http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c047.htm

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi here Lord Brahma explains about his previous manifestations to lord Vishnu....I want to know is he referring to previous Kalpas or previous Mahakalpas